# Is the mtime property of the stats object provided by fs.stat always a valid http-date?

Tags: node.js, http-headers, last-modified, fs

I'm using `fs.stats` to get the modified time (`mtime`) of a file so that I can put that information into a `last-modified` header when I serve that file. Is this property guaranteed to provide me with a valid `http-date` every time?

In other words, will this property always give me something which I can safely pass into a `last-modified` header?

Comment: The format is the same,but in [rfc2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html),it says:`An origin server MUST NOT send a Last-Modified date which is later than the server's time of message origination.` I think you'd better verify the `mtime` before send to client.

Comment: @osrpt What if I'm sending a file that I just created specifically for this request? The last modified date (and creation date) is necessarily going to be later than the time when the request was made.

Comment: How can I even know when the request was made?

Comment: I'm confused,why can't you know when the request was made? You are making a response,you must know there is a request.

Comment: @osrpt I know when I receive the request, but not when it was sent. There is always a delay, and sometimes it is big. So if I set the Last-Modified header to the time when my server receives the request, this will be after the time when the client has sent the request anyways. Why not then set it just a bit later still, to the time when the resource I'm sending back is created?